# From system of equations to linear algebra, sets, and linear independance

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have the equations:

$$
x + 2y -3z = 7\\[1em] 
2x + 3y +1z = 2\\[1em]
x + 1y -2z = 0
$$
And in general, writing it in column form we can do:
\begin{align}
    x& \begin{bmatrix}
           a_{1} \\
           a_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           a_{m} 
         \end{bmatrix} + y \begin{bmatrix}
           b_{1} \\
           b_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           b_{m} 
         \end{bmatrix} +
z \begin{bmatrix}
           c_{1} \\
           c_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           c_{m} 
         \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
           b_{1} \\
           b_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           b_{m} 
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

I'm just started on this but yet from Wikipedia this seems to be a linear combination of vectors, these ones holding the coefficients from the former equations.

I understand that, if 2 "rows" (say the head of each column vector) are the same or multiples of each other, then there won't be unique solution.

If one "row" is all zeros but not zero on the **b** there won't be solution.

**Question**

But I can't get the implications of 2 vectors say **a** and **b** being a linear combination of each other. What is the problem or important result if they do?

Also, is this a stronger condition that saying they need to be a "set"?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are referring to. What would be the exact condition and exactly for what?

Comment: @Berci linear independence, for the set of vectors

Comment: Which set of vectors? The given column vectors? The row vectors? Or the solutions? Do you have a specific statement in mind about their linear combinations / independence?

Comment: Suppose the column vectors $a$ and $b$ are linearly dependent, so that $\alpha a + \beta b = 0$ for some scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If the scalars $x,y,z$ satisfy $xa + yb + zc = d$, then we also have $(x+\alpha) a + (y+ \beta) b + zc = d$. (We have merely added zero on the left.) So if the linear system $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = d$ has a solution, the solution is not unique.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. But I still don't understand your question..

Comment: By the way, you seem to have two different column vectors with components $b_1, \ldots, b_n$.

Comment: @littleO will have to read that a few times thanks. Yes that's a mistake. They are different.